# Multiple distinct replaces using RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write some Python code that will replace some unwanted string using RegEx. The code I have written has been taken from another question on this site.

I have a text:

```
text_1=u'I\u2019m \u2018winning\u2019, I\u2019ve enjoyed none of it. That\u2019s why I\u2019m withdrawing from the market,\u201d wrote Arment.'
```

I want to remove all the \u2019m, \u2019s, \u2019ve and etc..

The code that I've written is given below:

```
rep={"\n":" ","\n\n":" ","\n\n\n":" ","\n\n\n\n":" ",u"\u201c":"", u"\u201d":"", u"\u2019[a-z]":"", u"\u2013":"", u"\u2018":""}
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
text = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], text_1)
```

The code works perfectly for:

```
"u"\u201c":"", u"\u201d":"", u"\u2013":"" and u"\u2018":""
```

However, It doesn't work that great for:

```
u"\u2019[a-z]  : The presence of [a-z] turns rep into \\[a\\-z\\] which doesnt match.
```

## The output I am looking for is:

```
text_1=u'I winning, I enjoyed none of it. That why I withdrawing from the market,wrote Arment.'
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about the newlines completely changes the answer. For this, I think building the expression using a loop is actually less legible than just using better formatting in the pattern itself.

```
replacements = {'newlines': ' ',
                'deletions': ''}
pattern = re.compile(u'(?P<newlines>\n+)|'
                     u'(?P<deletions>\u201c|\u201d|\u2019[a-z]?|\u2013|\u2018)')

def lookup(match):
    return replacements[match.lastgroup]

text = pattern.sub(lookup, text_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is actually the escaping, this code does what you want more directly:

```
remove = (u"\u201c", u"\u201d", u"\u2019[a-z]?", u"\u2013", u"\u2018")
pattern = re.compile("|".join(remove))
text = pattern.sub("", text_1)
```

I've added the `?` to the u2019 match, as I suppose that's what you want as well given your test string.

For completeness, I think I should also link to the [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) package which may actually be more closely what you're trying to achieve by removing these characters.

Comment: HI Chthonicdaemon, Thanks for the answer and the link. However, there is a small problem. The text file I am dealing with has many "\n" and I want to replace all (\n with a whitespace) and all (other unwanted strings with None).  I have updated the original expression in my post, Kindly have a look. Moreover, I want to do the whole stuff by scanning the file only once.

Comment: @Sam That changes the question quite a bit, so much so that I've added a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is this regex:

```
X = re.compile(r'((\\)(.*?) ')
text = re.sub(X, ' ', text_1)
```